# Pass property from object within array as Binding

Tags: swiftui

I want to to dynamically render card views matching the count of objects within an array. A single card view consists of a title, image and selected property, where the selected property should be from type `@Binding`. So my question is, how can I convert the bool value from the specific object within my array to a `@Binding`.

```
struct CardType: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    var title: String
    var image: String
    var selected: Bool
}

ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false, content: {
 HStack(spacing: 20) {
   ForEach(cardTypes) { cardType in
    PartialIcon(title: cardType.title, image: cardType.image, selected: cardType.selected)
   }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false, content: {
 HStack(spacing: 20) {
   ForEach(Array(cardTypes.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, cardType in
    PartialIcon(title: cardType.title, image: cardType.image, selected: self.$cardTypes[index].selected)
   }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works fine! But I wonder how the solution would look like with using the array of `CardType` and finding the right index from the specific `cardType`.